# What do double quotes signify in Xcode's search paths?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, search-path

Tonight we had an annoying issue that only presented itself in Xcode's command line builds, not from Xcode's GUI.

When building from a machine with Xcode's GUI with a recursive User Header Search path of $PROJROOT, without double quotes, we experienced no issue. However, when building with Jenkins, which uses Xcode's command line build capability, errors were thrown that Headers were unfindable.

After an hour of poking around, someone decided to try to wrap the recurive $PROJROOT in double quotes, ("$PROJROOT"). Once this happened, Jenkins command line building of the project was finally successful.

So we don't fully understand the ramifications of wrapping our search paths in quotes, or omitting the quotes.

Can anyone shed some light on what exactly was causing this issue? What double quotes signify to the compiler from the command line vs the GUI?

Comment: What does this have to do with the bf programming language? Or were you just taking some creative liberties with your tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More than likely the paths on your build machine have a space inside them (e.g. "`Macintosh HD/My Project/`").  That tends to confuse things when calling tools from the command line, because the command line parser doesn't know that the space character is part of a path or if it's starting off another command line argument, so this is why it's always good to wrap paths within double quotes.

Another option is to use backslashes with spaces (e.g. `Macintosh\ HD/My\ Project/`), but that's a little harder to keep track of and harder on the eyes.

Comment: This really must be the issue, I found a hint in the docs pointing towards this last night, but wasn't sure it was the case. However, you're the second one to say this is the case, so I've gotta accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Bash word splitting when some tool is executing another binary via the shell.

Barely useful man page documentation:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting

Detailed description of word splitting:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

I don't have enough reputation to post the last 3 as links.

Common pitfall when dealing with filenames (#1 on this list):
mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Compare Posix system()...
stackoverflow.com/questions/5666962/will-posix-system3-call-to-an-asynchronous-shell-command-return-immediately

To NSTask (which builds an array of arguments, hence no word-splitting)...
stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app